# Definite Double Integral Bounded by Polar Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following:
$$\iint\limits_D e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}dA$$ where $D$ is the region inside the circle $(x-1)^{2}+y^{2} = 1$ but outside the circle $x^{2}+y^{2} = 1$.

What I've got so far:

$x^{2}+y^{2} = 1$ is the circle centred on the origin with radius 1, and $(x-1)^{2}+y^{2} = 1$ is the same circle but centred on $(1,0)$. It seems it should be easier to evaluate this in polar coordinates, largely because $e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ simplifies nicely to $r^{2}$ once I substitute the polar values of x and y.

Using polar coordinates then, $$D = \left\{(r, \Theta) \mid 1 \leq r \leq 2 \cos \Theta, -\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \Theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}\right\}$$

This results in the double integral $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{1}^{2\cos\Theta}e^{(r\cos\Theta)^{2}+(r\sin\Theta)^{2}}r\ dr\ d\Theta\ =\ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{1}^{2\cos\Theta}e^{r^{2}}r\ dr\ d\Theta$$

I tried substituting $u = r^{2},\ du = 2rdr$, and ended up with $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(e^{4\cos^{2}\Theta}-e)d\Theta$$

After a lot of messing around, I tried some online calculators, and it seems like they're telling me this can't be evaluated. I thought that this meant I should try using Cartesian coordinates, so I tried that, but I also ended up with something I couldn't figure out how to evaluate: $$D_{1} = \left\{(x,y) \mid \frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 1, \root\of{1-x^{2}}\leq  y \leq +\root\of{1-(x-1)^{2}} \right\}$$ $$D_{2} = \left\{(x,y) \mid 1 \leq x \leq 2,0 \leq  y \leq +\root\of{1-(x-1)^{2}} \right\}$$

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to write this, but the idea was to use the parts of D in the first quadrant and fourth quadrant separately, and add them. $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ are the parts in the first quadrant only.

At this point though, I have no idea how I'd go about figuring this all out with the piecemeal functions. The textbook generally just glossed over this kind of situation and said if it's hard, solve for x instead of y, which I can't do in this situation, as I end up with $x(x-2)=-y^{2}$.

I'm doing Calc III online, and the teacher is permanently MIA, only emerging to grade assignments a month or two after they're submitted, so it's just me and my textbook and the internet. I'd love just being pointed in the right direction, so I at least know I'm banging my head against the correct wall. TIA!

Comment: It is not correct to write about your teacher in such way, even in a half-joking way. You probably don’t know all the details.

Comment: @Aig that's kind of a weird complaint to give to someone who very clearly put in the effort to not only learn the material but also put in the effort to ask a good question on their first try. I don't appreciate the moralizing you're trying to do. Of course OP doesn't "know all the details", but that doesn't invalidate their right to complain about a legitimate education access issue.

Comment: Were you asked to solve the integral, only set it up, or provide upper and lower estimates to the integral? All three are common introductory calc III questions, and most of them don't involve solving the integral at all.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The question was "evaluate the integral exactly."

Comment: @Aig I don't know the details, but I do know that the only interaction I have with the teacher is when they mark my assignments, generally a month or two after submitting. Not even intended as a complaint really, just an explanation of why I'm here and not talking to them :)

Comment: I don't think this integral has an elementary answer. It would be impossible to go further than you did in that case.

Comment: @dolbek63 I totally understand that you wrote it in a good-hearted way, but still using *this exact abbreviation* in the current world might hurt someone reading this. It’s probably better to use the word “absent” instead.

Comment: isnt $ \frac{1}{2} e^{r^2}  $ a primitive of $ r e^{r^2} $ ?

Comment: It is, I just found it easier to do the substitution by hand. Either way, the result is the same, and I end up with something I can't integrate with respect to theta.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the limits of integration?
Integrating with respect to theta first, then with respect to r?
That typically involves first graphing the domain, then figuring how to rewrite the domain as $\theta (r_1)$ to $\theta (r_2)$.  Essentially rewrite the domain in terms of the inverse functions.  Frequently, this can make impossible integrals possible.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha (standard) can't find an exact expression for any of these double integrals.

Comment: ok, never mind.  Swapping the order of integration in polar form doesn't appear fruitful.